# The field Preço de Venda must be a number. MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tenho um campo, preço venda, que na model está desta forma:

```
  public decimal PrecoVenda { get; set; }
```

Na ViewModel ele está desta forma:

```
[Display(Name = "Preço de Venda")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatorio.")]
    public decimal PrecoVenda { get; set; }
```

E está é a View:

```
 <label asp-for="PrecoVenda" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input asp-for="PrecoVenda" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira o  preço de venda.">
                    <span asp-validation-for="PrecoVenda" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

Porém quando preenche os valores, com vírgula, por exempo "0,00"
Ele me retorna esta mensagem:

> The field Preço de Venda must be a number.

Se eu coloco "25.00", ao verificar o valor está "2500,00"

Comment: Tenta adicionar esse data anotattion: [DataType(DataType.Currency)]

Comment: Acontece a mesma coisa, ocorre o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver, seguindo o tutorial deste [link](http://cleytonferrari.com/validacao-de-data-e-moeda-asp-net-mvc-jquery-validation-em-portugues/)

Instalo esse pacote:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.pt-br
```

O jQuery Valitation é o responsável pela validação do lado do cliente, para globalizar ele para PT-Br precisamos criar um novo arquivo na pasta “Scripts” chamado “methods_pt.js” com o seguinte conteúdo:

```js
   /*
 * Localized default methods for the jQuery validation plugin.
 * Locale: PT_BR
 */
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    date: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value);
    },
    number: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

E chamo o script na página que eu preciso por último.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/methods_pt.js"));
```

Espero que possa ajudar ;)

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/180712)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, acabei de atualizar com a parte dos códigos.

Comment: Olá @Mariana!!! Estou tendo o mesmo problema com campos decimas... Fiz como vc citou no exemplo e resolveu o problema... Não funcionou para datas... Percebi que em fields do tipo Date , se vc informar uma data, ao clicar fora do input, fica aparecendo uma msg de erro pedindo para digitar a data... Vc sabe como resolver isso?